# Drywall Repair by the baseboard

Tags: drywall, repair, patching-drywall, hole-repair

How to fix drywall that is broken by the baseboard. The drywall is broken above and under where the baseboard is.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How?

Well, there a a few ways to do the repair.

The best way :

1- Remove the baseboard.

2- Cut out the damaged section. Replace with new drywall, backed with deadwood where needed.

3- Tape, mud, texture ( if needed)

4- Paint.

The shorter route would be to cut the section of baseboard, and perform steps 2 thru 4. replacing the baseboard and caulking the new joints. ( not always a good looking repair.)

Another way is to leave the baseboard, remove the damaged section and pull out the drywall behind the baseboard. ( a little bit of a PITA.)  Then steps 2-4.

You can also fill the hole with some compressed paper. Add some mesh tape and mud the entire area. It will probably take a few coats of mud and sanding between layers,  then steps 3 and 4.  This is something that may result in a mess or look good depending on your skill level )

Comment: How do you like this South Florida weather?

Comment: It's better than most of the country.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to cut out the damaged drywall leaving the baseboard in place. Remove all the drywall behind the baseboard. Cut a piece of new drywall to fit from the floor behind the baseboard up to the top of the repair. Attach with drywall clips or some wood strips attached to the existing drywall to support the new piece and screw in place. Then tape and paint.